# logging to stackdriver from winston

Tags: google-cloud-platform, winston, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am using the library [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/logging-winston) to log to Stackdriver from Node.js.
However, the logs aren't showing up - I think because I'm not specifying a metadata resource, such as '[global](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries)'.  How do I do that?

```
var winston = require('winston');
var transport = require('@google-cloud/logging-winston');

winston.add(transport, {
  projectId: 'myproject',
  keyFilename: 'google_key.json',
  level: 'warn' // log at 'warn' and above 
});

winston.error('warp nacelles offline');
```

Comment: Can you provide some code? We need to see your tryouts before. Maybe error somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to add a 'label' field to the configuration, like so:

```
winston.add(transport, {
  projectId: 'myproject',
  keyFilename: 'google_key.json',
  level: 'warn', // log at 'warn' and above,
  label: 'Global'
});
```